# Phpmyadmin shows random number of rows in database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

on VPS I have PHPMyAdmin 5.0.4
Through PHP script from XML, I got from the vendor I have imported data in tables. One table is large and says the number of rows is `~71,959`.

When I enter the table I get a different number of rows:
`Showing rows 0 - 24 (72330 total, Query took 0.0003 seconds.)`

On each refresh both numbers show different values and they are random - sometimes greater, sometimes smaller number.

When I query through CLI I always get the same result:

```
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|     72217 |
+-----------+
```

Is this a problem with the configuration of phpmyadmin? On other servers phpmyadmin always showed the exact number of rows.

Comment: MySQL provides table estimates. `select count(*) from table` is the way to get the accurate number.

Comment: @danblack I see, but the same table, same data on another server (Cpanel) shows the exact number, never "estimate".

Answer (score 0):

After googling more I found the solution to my problem. In phpMyAdmin configuration I have changed the field `$cfg['MaxExactCount']`

More about the field:
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=maxexactcount#cfg_MaxExactCount

After that my numbers were correct.

Note:

- there were some comments on other sites that it worked after they have restarted PHP and MySQL. I didn't do that and it worked for me.